# How to append the count of child vertices in Gremlin?

Tags: graphql, gremlin, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3, gremlin-server

Here's the graph I'm working on.

```
g = TinkerGraph.open().traversal()
first_generation = g.addV('person').property('id', '1').next()
second_generation = g.addV('person').property('id', '2').next()
third_generation = g.addV('person').property('id', '3').next()
third_generation_1 = g.addV('person').property('id', '4').next()
fourth_generation = g.addV('person').property('id', '5').next()
g.addE('child').from(first_generation).to(second_generation)
g.addE('child').from(second_generation).to(third_generation)
g.addE('child').from(second_generation).to(third_generation_1)
g.addE('child').from(third_generation).to(fourth_generation)
```

Here, I want to fetch the list of all people with the number of children they have.

```
[{'id': 1, 'children': 1}, {'id': 2, 'children': 2}]
```

I read about `sideEffect` but can't seem to append the result of sideEffect to the output.

Any suggestions on how we can achieve the desired output ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should probably use `project()`

```
gremlin> g.V().hasLabel('person').
......1>   project('id','children').
......2>     by('id').
......3>     by(out('child').count())
==>[id:1,children:1]
==>[id:2,children:2]
==>[id:3,children:1]
==>[id:4,children:0]
==>[id:5,children:0]
```

It takes each vertex and transforms it into a `Map` of the specified keys. The `by()` modulators then specify what the values of those keys should be.

Comment: Any chance that I can project a list of child IDs instead of the count ? 
@stephen-mallette

Comment: `by()` takes a number of different types of arguments. you can see in the last one it just takes a traversal which uses the current vertex being projected as the start...so, just change the `count()` to `id().fold()` to get the ids and then fold them to a `List`